# Trabalhar com imagem em C#

Tags: c#, imagem

Tenho duas imagens:

[image: Escada]

[image: menino]

Em tempo de execução, preciso unir as duas imagens. Podendo determinar a posição do boneco sobre a escada. Ambas as imagens estão em disco.

O resultado seria imagens como estas em base64:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Já existem bibliotecas que podem me ajudar com isso? Quais são as
>   melhores?

**Obs.: Estou em um projeto Asp.Net MVC .Net Framework 4**

Comment: Basta você pegar as propriedades MARGIN das imagens e altera-las

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize da seguinte maneira:

```
var Ima = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\kOWnj.jpg");
var Imb = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\AlaDL.jpg");
Image IMGfinal = MergeTwoImages(Ima, Imb);
```

Ja fiz com as 2 imagens:

```
public Bitmap MergeTwoImages(Image ImagemA, Image ImagemB)
        {
            if (ImagemA == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("ImagemA");
            }

            if (ImagemB == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("ImagemB");
            }

            int outputImageWidth = ImagemA.Width + ImagemB.Width;
            int outputImageHeight = ImagemA.Height + ImagemB.Height;

            int imagemAx = 0;
            int imagemAy = 100;

            int imagemBx = 140;
            int imagemBy = -10;

            Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
            {
                graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Rectangle(new Point(), new Size(outputImageWidth,outputImageHeight))); //fundo branco
                graphics.DrawImage(ImagemA, new Rectangle(new Point(imagemAx, imagemAy), ImagemA.Size), new Rectangle(new Point(), ImagemA.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);//imagem 1
                graphics.DrawImage(ImagemB, new Rectangle(new Point(imagemBx, imagemBy), ImagemB.Size), new Rectangle(new Point(), ImagemB.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);//imagem 2
            }

            return outputImage;
        }
```

[Voce tambem encontra outras maneiras nesse link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383123/merge-two-images-to-create-a-single-image-in-c-net)